# Datapacket header structure

Tags: ethernet

The datapacket headers for any given packet follows the struture:

```
ethernet|ip|tcp|ftp|data
```

If I am to use ftp connection. Is the reason ethernet comes first historical? Since globally the ethernet adress of my router and PC is not of first concern. I would logically assume that the IP header would come first, it is the main info needed to route my request correctly, not the ethernet, it only becomes relevant when routing a packet from my local LAN to my PC.

I am confused..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assuming the Ethernet header stays with the data from source to destination.

The Ethernet header only exists on Ethernet links, and each different Ethernet link will have a different header.

At every router hop, the layer 2 header (Ethernet) is removed, then the IP header is examined, the routing decision is made, and a new layer 2 header is added.  If the layer 2 connection is Ethernet, then an Ethernet header is added.  If it's Wi-fi, then an 802.11 header.  Sonet, HDLC, *etc.* all have their own layer 2 headers.

The Ethernet header you receive was added to the packet by the router closest to you.